# Сравнение вариантов объявления массивов

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 варианта объявления массивов в javascript

```
var i = []
```

И

```
var i = new Array()
```

Какой вариант лучше, как по мне `var i = []` он более проще. Мне нужен ответ профессионала где быстрее и.т.д.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/new-array-vs

Comment: Ха, оно и ясно Array это функция

Comment: Array - это не функция

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `typeof Array === 'function'`

Comment: и кстати `Array instanceof Function`

Comment: _Мне нужен ответ профессионала где быстрее_ - объявления практически равнозначны. В любом случае, чтобы заметить разницу нужно очень постараться

Comment: @Darth ага. и `typeof Object === 'function'`....но ты меня не понял, поэтому не будем вдаваться в подробности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Это два варианта объявления массивов, выбираешь тот, что тебе удобнее/привычнее

При объявлении **new Array**, ты можно указать либо элементы массива, либо длину массива. В этом и разница. А по скорости - **разницы нет**.